# Executable file in ruby

Tags: ruby

any way to create an 'executable' file in ruby so you can run file.rb with ./file

I know you can just run ruby files ruby filename.rb

I also want to be able to send arguments so ./file argument_1 argument_2

Comment: File contents: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby\n p 'hi!'` then run `chmod 2775 ./file.txt` then you can run `./file.txt` and the output will be `"hi!"`

Answer (score 1):

## run an ordinate ruby file

1. Add `#! /usr/bin/env ruby` to your first line of `file.rb` file.
2. giving execute permission to this file: `$ chmod +x file.rb`
3. run: `$ ./file.rb`

## run ruby file with parameter from commandline:

use `ARGV`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
puts " parameter0 is: #{ARGV[0]}"
puts " parameter1 is: #{ARGV[1]}"
```

output:

```
$ ./test.rb a b
 parameter0 is: a
 parameter1 is: b
```

## doubli click to run .rb file in windows

1. install ruby in windows
2. mouse right click `.rb` file
3. open with ...
4. choose ruby program. as the "default program"

for more details, refer to: https://techforluddites.com/windows-10-change-the-default-programs-for-opening-files/

Comment: This is the correct answer for Unix-like systems. I don't think hashbangs work out-of-the-box on Windows, and to be honest I don't really know how to emulate them offhand.

Comment: I updated my answer for default open method in windows.